How to attract more users and have more questions?
Mi chiedo se sia possibile rendere più attivo questo sito. Per quello che ho visto finora gli utilizzatori sono spesso  stranieri che fanno domande di carattere grammaticale e/o ortografico. Personalmente ho cercato di fare domande più di carattere etimologico con riferimento a modi di dire comunemente usati nella lingua di ogni giorno. Mi chiedo come si possa attrarre nuovi users e fare sì che il numero delle domande aumenti. Potrebbe, ad esempio, un maggior uso della lingua inglese con riferimento a domande e risposte su questioni della lingua italiana,  aiutare ad avere nuovi users? Qualcuno ha qualche altra idea? 
I wonder whether it is possible to make  this site more attractive. So far I have seen that users are often foreigners who ask mainly grammatical and / or spelling questions. Personally I have tried to ask questions about the etymology  of  idioms commonly used in everyday language. I wonder how we can attract new users and   increase the numbers of questions. Could it help,  for example, if  the English language were more widely used with reference to questions and answers on issues of the Italian language?  Any other suggestion will be appreciated!

Remember to translate the question to English so that everyone can understand it.

Well, I'm here because I'm interested in Neapolitan Songs. But being Neapolitan off-topic, I just don't remember to log in :)

@c.p. - did you look for a Neapolitan dialect  site. I guess there must be at least  a few.

Yeah, sure, in area51... anyway, not being Italian, I'm aware that Neapolitan is not a dialect.

Definire il problema
Penso che ci siano fondamentalmente due ostacoli alla diffusione del sito:

La stessa piattaforma StackExchange
La cultura della comunità

Il software è stato creato originariamente per rispondere a quesiti d'informatica. Da questo derivano alcune scelte, come l'uso di Markdown e la difficoltà ad inserirsi nella comunità, che non necessariamente funzionano così bene in altri contesti. Si possono vedere i privilegi qui (grazie a Charo).
Questa impostazione funziona bene per l'informatica, dove la comunità è fortemente internazionale e di variegate capacità. Inoltre è possibile, se non necessario, dare risposte precise.
La cosa non vale per una lingua madre dove la maggior parte delle persone hanno un'esperienza decennale, e per cui esistono già autorità ben stabilite.Detto in altri termini, StackOverflow doveva competere con risposte imprecise e fuori tema, italian.stackexchange deve competere con l'Accademia della Crusca, il cui compito ufficiale è proprio quello di dare risposte sulla lingua italiana.
Possibili soluzioni
La vocazione naturale del sito è quello di attrarre stranieri e italiani interessati alla lingua italiana.
Pertanto la soluzione più ovvia sarebbe avere più domande che interessano entrambi i tipi di utenti, come ad esempio quelle di confronto tra la lingua italiana e altre. Domande che diano la possibilità di dire la propria ed imparare qualcosa dal confronto. 
Esistono altre soluzioni meno ortodosse, come ad esempio permettere domande legate all'evoluzione della lingua (es. quando il latino è diventato italiano ?) o attualmente proibite come quella sulla scrittura o sulle risorse (che io intendo come "dove trovare una versione italiana e inglese della Divina Commedia").
Purché si trattasse di domande e non di argomenti da forum di discussione ritengo che potrebbero essere utili. La domanda è ovviamente se si vuole farlo.

Define the problem
I think there are mainly two obstacles to a more widespread usage of the website:

The StackExchange platform
The culture of the community

The software was originally created to answer computer science questions. This has lead to some choices, as the use of Markdown and the difficulty of becoming part of a community, that don't work that well in other contexts. You could see privileges here (thanks to Charo).
This rule works well for computer science, where the communinity is strongly internationalized and with different levels of competence. Furthermore, in computer science is possibile, if not necessary, to give precise answers. (Interested english speaker can learn more about the development of the platform searching on the blog of one the main authors)
The same is not true for a mother tongue, where most people have a decennial experience, and for which already exists estabilished authorities. Put in different terms, StackOverflow had to compete against asnwers that were imprecise and off topic while italian.stackexchange must compete against l'Accademia della Crusca, whose official duty is exactly that of giving answers about the italian language.
Possibile solutions
The natural calling of the website is that of drawing in foreign and italian people interested in the italian language.
Given that the obvious solution would be to have more questions that interest both type of users, such as one that compare italian language with other ones. Questions that gives the chance to everybody to give his/her own opinion and learn something from the debate.
There are less orthodox solutions, such as allowing questions linked to the evolution of the language (ie. when latin became italian ?) o currently forbidden as that on writing o on resources (that I mean as "where do find a version of Divine Commedy in both italian and english")
As long as they were proprer questions and not forum debates I think they could be useful. The obvious question is whether we want to go there.

Trovo molto interessante l'idea di confrontare la lingua italiana e altre lingue.

Potresti cercare di tradurre la tua risposta in iglese in modo che tutti la possano capire? Questa è la politica di meta.italian.SE.

Non capisco cosa vuoi dire con l'affermazione "per porre una domanda devi prima fare altre cose, come rispondere ad un'altra domanda".

intendo dire che se hai zero punti non puoi fare una domanda.

Ma, all'inizio si ha un punto e non zero punti, e si possono fare domande! Vuoi dire porre domande qui, in meta?

Hai ragione sull'avere un punto e non zero, ma sul fatto che si possano sempre fare domande non è vero. In alcuni casi, immagino determinati dalla "credibilità" della tua email e del modo in cui ti sei registrato (account facebook vs nuovo account StackExchange/hai javascript attivato ?) devi avere almeno 10 punti per farlo. Questa almeno è stata la mia esperienza. In ogni caso il mio punto principale è che prima di poter partecipare completamente devi "provare la tua affidabilità" il che restringe in qualche misura la partecipazione dei nuovi utenti.

Qui puoi vedere che con 1 punto si possono creare post (domande e risposte).

Grazie per tradurre il post in inglese!

Ti assicuro che volevo porre una domanda e non mi è stato possibile farlo. Forse non era la domanda di per sé ma quanto riportato qui sulle restrizioni dei nuovi utenti. Cioè il fatto che avevo messo troppi link. Comunque sia l'esempio in sé non è importante, ritengo che la presenza di restrizioni restrizioni può essere un problema quando vi sono tante alternative. Quindi la soluzione è creare qualcosa di diverso.

C'è poco da fare credo, ormai sono passati due anni e il trend delle domande tende ad assere orribilmente stabile fra una e due al dì, e senza il contributo di @charo le statistiche sarebbero ancora peggiori.
Secondo me è che, tanto in Italia quanto all'estero, dell'italiano non interessa niente a quasi nessuno, di talché ripongo poche speranze si possano attrarre nuovi 'user' in futuro.
Chiaramente, così continuando le cose, Italian Language è prossimo a liquefarsi.

Sono in parte d'accordo. In realtà anche i siti gemelli sulla lingua francese e tedesca non sono molto  attivi ( più di quello italiano comunque) . Secondo me ci sono molti  stranieri e italiani interessati alla nostra lingua  e questo potrebbe essere uno strumento di aiuto. Probabilmente gli users con maggior reputazione  dovrebbero essere più attivi anche su fronte delle domande .  P.S. Cosa vuol dire "di talché  "? :))

I don't quite agree: I don't think that Italian language doesn't interest to almost anyone.  In my opinion, the site is growing. It is doing so at a very slow rate, but it's growing and probably we should be patient if we want to see the results. Maybe it's difficult for a site about a language to generate so many questions per day as sites about other topics.  For instance, Spanish.SE  has lots of users, but only 0.8 questions per day.

'According to me' sounds strange to me, however. I prefer 'In my opinion' :)

That's true, @ElberichSchneider! I've corrected it. Thanks!

Vedendo che questa risposta aveva un punteggio negativo l'ho votata. I downvote andrebbero usati con parsimonia nel sito normale, e forse addirittura vietati qui (su meta), perchè queste discussioni servono a raccogliere pareri personali, e nessuno può essere sicuro al 100% che un parere personale sia così sbagliato  da meritare un downvote.
